# Python: How to move N lines from one file to another

Tags: python, copy, cut

I am trying something like this, but in Python and not PowerShell:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105376/how-to-move-n-lines-from-one-file-to-another

Can somebody help me? I need to move (cut, not only copy) the first 100 lines from a text file to another empty/new text file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 100
with open("C:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy/from",'r') as f1:
    data = f1.readlines()
with open("C:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy/from",'w') as f1:
    for line in data[x:]:
        f1.write(line)
with open("C:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy/to",'w') as f2:
    for line in data[:x]:
        f2.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! However you have a Typo. The first `for` line means to be `[x:]` and the 2nd `for` line `[:x]`. Then it works. Thank you again!